# How to split a 7 GB .VOB file for DVD authoring?

Tags: linux, dvd

I have a 7 GB VOB file which I created from a DVD using ffmpeg dump to remove CSS protection (it is legal where I live to do so). Now, I want to create a DVD/.iso that will be understood by regular DVD players/appliances. How do I do it? Freeware and/or linux solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: One thing to take into account: A common single-layer DVD+/-R is only 4.3 GB.  You'll either need to get dual-layer blank DVDs or re-encode the movie to fit into the smaller space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DVDAuthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) for this. There is a good chance it will be available in your Linux distribution's package repository (it certainly is in Ubuntu).

DVDAuthor generates a correctly-formatted file structure for playback by standard DVD players, using files containing an MPEG-2 stream as input and an XML file to control the operation. The simplest format is the "one chapter, one source" usage described [here](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/doc/x35.html#AEN37).

For example, you might create an XML file like:

```
<dvdauthor>
    <vmgm />
    <titleset>
        <titles>
            <pgc>
                <vob file="your_extracted_vob.vob" />
            </pgc>
        </titles>
    </titleset>
</dvdauthor>
```

Then invoke the dvdauthor command with:

```
$ dvdauthor -o /tmp/dvd-image -x your_xml_file.xml
```

After the command finishes, there will be a directory of DVD-formatted files in /tmp/dvd-image, which you can burn to a DVD using the usual growisofs command.